# Puppy growling at the ball

Tags: dogs, behavior, toys

I gave my three-month puppy an old ball as a toy.  When he plays with the ball, he growls and bites the ball.  I'm afraid of he becomes aggressive.

Is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they get aggressive with you when you take away the toy?

If his growling and biting is limited to the toy and he is able to "snap out of it" (also a useful command phrase to use, possibly in conjunction with a sharp hand clap to shift the dogs attention) then that seems normal. Your puppy might just be "getting into it" with their toy. Good dog toy practice for you might also involve putting the toy(s) away when play time is over (somewhere out of sight if need be, possibly just in a bucket and you can train them to retrieve and deposit toys at the appropriate times).

If the dog gets aggressive, remains aggressive and the aggression escalates (stiff posture, raised hackles, baring teeth, barking, snapping, nipping, biting, etc.) or the dog gets aggressive with you or others, this is not normal. If this is the case, consider talking to a veterinarian behaviorist. You can ask your vet if they can recommend one or a dog behavior training class in your area.

Here's [an article with some overview and suggestions](http://healthypets.mercola.com/sites/healthypets/archive/2015/07/27/puppy-play.aspx).

Play time is part of how you relate to your dog. You want them to have fun, but remember that you are the boss. Another command suggestion if your dog gets overly playful with strangers: consider distinguishing the "down" command for "lie down" from the "off" command for "get off that". Also, especially while training for the first 18 months of your pup's life, be stern with the command voice (and look them in the eye) and once the command is obeyed, use an affectionate voice (and smile) and tell them "good (command)" - i.e. "Sit!" ::dog sits:: "Good sit."